# Salesforce login using Access Token

Tags: login, accesstoken

I am having Refresh Token to generate Access Tokens in Salesforce and by using api calls I can successfully retrieve data using Postman... But my problem is I am automating one of the scenarios in Salesforce including login... So is there a way to login into Salesforce by using Access Token in Web Browser so that I can skip the verification step which is asking each time when I start my test Automation?

My instance is **https://xxxxxcorporationeu--staging.lightning.force.com** and I need to proceed to this page after login 
**https://xxxxxcorporationeu--staging.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home**